# How do I create a blacklist or whilelist of branches for git hooks?

Tags: git, githooks, sh

I am trying to add some functionality to git's post-recieve-email hook to either ignore specific branches or to only email on specific branches (obviously these options would be mutually exclusive).  I would like to not hard-code a list of branches into the hook itself, but instead make use of the [hooks] section of a repository's config file.

Where I'm struggling is in keeping the shell bourne shell compatible while still being able to see if a branch name is part of the whitelist or blacklist.

I think that I could do something like this:

```
whitelist=$(git hooks.branch_whitelist)
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
  branch_name=${refname#refs/heads/}
  for wl_branch in $whitelist
  do
    if [ $branch_name = $wl_branch ] 
      ... send email ...
      break # prevents multiple emails on malformed whitelist string
  done
done
```

For some reason, the above seems just wrong.  Does anyone have a better way of checking if a string is a member of a list (not a supported data structure in bourne if I understand correctly)?

Edit: It would also be nice to be able to do partial string matching (e.g. blacklist all that -dev branches), but the only answer I find over and over is the double bracket method from bash.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a shell issue than a git issue, but I already wrote such a thing.  Here's the function:

```
# Is $1 in a list?
in_list()
{
        local match i

        match="$1"
        shift
        set -- $(echo "$@" | sed 's/,/ /g')
        for i do
                [ "$i" = "$match" ] && return 0 # i.e., "true"
        done
        return 1 # i.e., "false"
}
```

and an example of using it:

```
if in_list $branch_name $(git config --get hooks.foo); then ...
```

The form of the list is white-space-and-or-comma-separated entries:

```
git config hooks.foo eh,bee,sea,de,e
```

or:

```
git config hooks.foo 'eh bee sea de e'
```

(or any mix of the two).

If you want to support some kind of regular expression or shell globbing, it should be pretty obvious<sup>1</sup> how to modify `in_list` to do that.

Note that the newest-and-best post-receive-email hook is now a Python script rather than a shell script, though.

---

<sup>1</sup>If it's not obvious after all: `[` is actually a command (also spelled `test`), so you can run any command to compare `$match` vs `$i`.  `expr` can do (basic) regular expressions:

```
expr "$match" : "${i}$" >/dev/null && return 0
```

would see if `$match` (the branch name) matches any regular expression in the list.  The reason for using `${i}$` is that `expr` left-anchors the test (a la Python's `re.match()`) but does not right-anchor, so `.*-dev` matches `x-devote` as well as `x-dev`, which might not be what you meant.  With this you might set `hooks.foo` to `.*-dev`, for instance (or include that in the list of values).

For shell globbing (in plain `/bin/sh`), use `case` instead of `test` / `[`:

```
case "$match" in
$i) return 0;;
esac
```

Here you would set `hooks.foo` to `*-dev`, or something including `*-dev`.